# How to import font style to css and use in a page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use a font called `neontubes` and have the following code which I have imported and placed in my style css in WordPress.

```
  @font-face { 
    font-family: 'neontubes';
    src:  url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.eot'); 
    src:  url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('https://bitbucket.org/kenneth jensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
          url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.ttf')
```

I then tried styling with div class.

```
.event {font-family: neontubes;}
```

Nothing happened?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semi-colon after your first URL.  Also, you can't have multiple src properties.  Here's an example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNovaLight;
    src: url("/Portals/0/Fonts/ProximaNova-Light.woff") format("woff"), url("/Portals/0/Fonts/ProximaNova-Light.ttf")  format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So how do i get this neontubes font to work on my site?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make it much clearer than that without doing it for you.  Just follow the example syntax and make sure to check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) or other online documentation if you are still confused.